# Text shade is too light

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface

I don't know if I share this experience with other members of the Academia.SE community, but for me text shade is way too light. For me, it makes it harder to read (and focus on content) plus, after not long time (~10min?) slightly painful (~dry eyes).

I know it has some positive consequences too (i.e. not spending too much time on Academia.SE), but I am not sure if it is desired effect overall.

Why I am writing it now? In general I prefer dark text (like `#000000`) to gray one. During the design phase I didn't want to be too biased (especially as I do like the design). I though that I would get used to it. But I didn't (it's not getting any better).

I know it may *look* nice. But I am here not for *looking*, but for *reading*.

Are you experiencing a similar problem?

(If it is only my, I will do some CSS hacking on my side, but if a non-trivial fraction of users share my pain, then it might be worth talking about tweaking it globally.)

Comment: I concur. I find the main text too light to read without some effort, and there seem to be other instances of text that are even lighter.

Comment: I strongly concur with the "complaint" about too-light text. I like to keep the screen brightness as low as possible...

Comment: Is there any evidence that the SE admins will be willing to fix any of our design issues now ?

Comment: A light-on-dark *option* would be great, too. I'm a big fan of light grey text on a nearly-black background. But I suspect this might be too much work to integrate into the rest of the site design.

Comment: @Suresh Still, it might be worth trying. I have always found SE team helpful.

Comment: What I mean is, how do we get them to look at this issue ?

Comment: On a related note, the ratings of the questions in the "what's related" list, displayed in white on a pale grey background, are almost completely unreadable.

Comment: I just ran across this link on the UX Stack Exchange site, and it made me think of our lack-of-constrast-y site we have here in Academia: http://contrastrebellion.com/